# Cant understand advantage of overridden implementation of equals method in ConcurrentHashMap

Tags: java, java.util.concurrent

Most of the map classes in Java override `AbstractMap` and use its implementation of `equals` method which checks that:

1. passed object is of type Map
2. has same length
3. contains all the entries present in `this`

   ```
   if (o == this)
       return true;

   //check that passed object is of type Map
   if (!(o instanceof Map))
       return false;
   Map<?,?> m = (Map<?,?>) o;

   //check that passed object has same length
   if (m.size() != size())
       return false;

   //passed object contains all the entries
   try {
       Iterator<Entry<K,V>> i = entrySet().iterator();
       while (i.hasNext()) {
           Entry<K,V> e = i.next();
           K key = e.getKey();
           V value = e.getValue();
           if (value == null) {
               if (!(m.get(key)==null && m.containsKey(key)))
                   return false;
           } else {
               if (!value.equals(m.get(key)))
                   return false;
           }
       }
   } catch (ClassCastException unused) {
       return false;
   } catch (NullPointerException unused) {
       return false;
   }

   return true;
   ```

But ConcurrentHashMap uses a different implementation where instead of matching length of both the maps, the entries present in passed map are also iterated and matched.

```
    if (o != this) {

        //check that passed object is of type Map
        if (!(o instanceof Map))
            return false;
        Map<?,?> m = (Map<?,?>) o;
        Node<K,V>[] t;
        int f = (t = table) == null ? 0 : t.length;
        Traverser<K,V> it = new Traverser<K,V>(t, f, 0, f);

        //passed object contains all the entries
        for (Node<K,V> p; (p = it.advance()) != null; ) {
            V val = p.val;
            Object v = m.get(p.key);
            if (v == null || (v != val && !v.equals(val)))
                return false;
        }

        //this contains all the entries of the passed object
        for (Map.Entry<?,?> e : m.entrySet()) {
            Object mk, mv, v;
            if ((mk = e.getKey()) == null ||
                (mv = e.getValue()) == null ||
                (v = get(mk)) == null ||
                (mv != v && !mv.equals(v)))
                return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
```

Since `equals` method is not thread safe even in `ConcurrentHashMap` can someone suggest what is the benefit of skipping length check and instead iterating and matching entries from passed object?

As pointed in answers below that size is not available as a direct field, this is the `equals` implementation which I believe is more efficient. Please clarify issues in this one. Mostly we are not doing any lookup in the last loop.

```
    if (o != this) {

        //check that passed object is of type Map
        if (!(o instanceof Map))
            return false;
        Map<?,?> m = (Map<?,?>) o;
        Node<K,V>[] t;
        int f = (t = table) == null ? 0 : t.length;
        Traverser<K,V> it = new Traverser<K,V>(t, f, 0, f);
        int thisSize=0;

        //passed object contains all the entries
        for (Node<K,V> p; (p = it.advance()) != null; ) {
            V val = p.val;
            Object v = m.get(p.key);
            if (v == null || (v != val && !v.equals(val)))
                return false;
            thisSize++;
        }

        //passed object is of the same size, ignoring any modifications since invocation of equals
        int passedObjectSize=0;
        for (Map.Entry<?,?> e : m.entrySet()) {
            Object mk, mv, v;
            if ((mk = e.getKey()) == null ||
                (mv = e.getValue()) == null){
                return false;
            }
            //ignore checking that get(mk) is same as mv
            passedObjectSize++;
        }
        return thisSize==passedObjectSize;
    }
    return true;
```

Comment: The equals method of CMH is thread-safe, it's just that the result is not very meaningful when concurrent modifications occur.

Answer (score 2):

I think that checking the size would be useless, when computing the size `Traverser` is not used at all, it uses a specialization of `LongAdder` (called `CounterCell`), so it takes time to compute the size and by the time this is done - the CHM could change entirely before traversing.

Even computing the `size` has no guarantees that it will be correct for example `CHM` could be mutated *while* computing the size - so that number would not be accurate.

So I guess this can be seen as an optimization: why compute the size if most of the time it is useless anyway.

Comment: I don't think it is because it is useless - in case of concurrent modification, all bets are off anyways. I think it is simply not worth it because the implementation is a lot more expensive (see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50875745/2513200)), but I think you are on the right track with investigating the `size()` implementaion.

Comment: @Hulk *I don't think it is because it is useless - in case of concurrent modification, all bets are off anyways* you say it yourself, all bets are off. Its like doing some work that would be irrelevant anyway (when computing `equals`), so why do it> To me that is the definition of `useless`...

Comment: Ok, what I meant was - the result of `equals()` is only meaningful if there are no concurrent modifications. When there are no concurrent modifications, the result of `size` is meaningful as well and might actually help, but calculating it is expensive, so it is not very attractive as a quick check.

Comment: Since you both are actively discussing in comments here let me just add my two cents: We all (and even javadoc) agree that we are not trying to cover the case of modifications happening during `equals` call. Now as far as keeping the implementation efficient is concerned, we need to see which of the following is more efficient: "finding size of passed map" vs "checking if all entries of passed map are in `this`". After looking at code it seems finding size of passed map would be more efficient as it does not involve lookup in `this` or am I missing something?

Comment: @user2935600 but what would be the point in computing the size (it would not prove that two different instances are equal), only to *traverse* the instances after that? So size, would not prove anything to begin with, so why do it?

Comment: matching size is not the only thing we do. we have also performed the check that passed object contains all entries present in `this`. And during this course we have also found size of `this`. That's why we are only left with checking whether there are any more entries in the passed object which its size would tell.

Comment: @user2935600 checking the size in equals in non-thread safe collections, is an optimization - it is faster to get a single field and if the sizes are different, the result is obviously false, otherwise traverse and check each element/bucket. For `CHM`, computing the size is useless (in case of `equals`) because if it returns different sizes, it does not yet mean that two instances of `CHM` are indeed different - you *still* have to traverse them. I don't understand your input on this

Comment: @Eugene have updated the question with sample code to explain what I meant. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

The implementation of `ConcurrentHashMap.size()` is quite different from most other `Map`s.

`HashMap` and `TreeMap` implement it by just returning the value of a private field `size` they maintain anyway.

`ConcurrentHashMap` does not maintain such a field. This would be difficult to implement in a non-blocking way while still allowing concurrent modifications to distinct buckets to interfere as little as possible with each other.

The Java 8 version I'm looking at has the following implementation

```
/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
public int size() {
    long n = sumCount();
    return ((n < 0L) ? 0 :
            (n > (long)Integer.MAX_VALUE) ? Integer.MAX_VALUE :
            (int)n);
}
```

where `sumCount()` iterates an array of `counterCells`.

This is a lot less attractive as a quick check than a simple field access.